# If/Else return TRUE when not true in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm catching the name of an user logged on `$userrow['name']` and then I'm using if/else to compare to 2 strings

```
    $user1 = "admin";
    $user2 = "Gil";
    if ($userrow['name'] == $user1 || $user2 ) {
        echo "true";
    }else{
        echo "false";
    }
```

in  this case my `$userrow['name']` its = "Andres" and obviously Andres != Gil || Admin

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I've no idea what your question is about. *"and obviously Andres != Gil"*??

Comment: You may accept the answer that you think appropriately answered your question by clicking the big check mark next to the question.

Comment: Classic *Thank you suckers!!!* type of OP.

Comment: @Fred-ii- given an OP who obviously doesn't know what he's doing, why in the world would you want to pressure him to accept answers? Incompetents accepting answers is a strictly bad thing for the site; it just leads to crap answers being pinned to the top of answer lists. Blindly encouraging people to accept answers seems actively harmful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is incorrect.  I will try in english to say what your `if` statement does:

> If `$userrow['name']` equals the value held in the variable `$user1`, or if the value held in the variable `$user2` is not *falsey* ...

In `$user2` you have the value "Gil".  Since "Gil" is not falsey (in other words, it is not false or null or zero), then it is considered to be *true* when evaluated within the context of an `if` statement.  I think this is what you want to say instead:

```
if ($userrow['name'] == $user1 || $userrow['name'] == $user2 ) {
```

Answer (score 4):

More maintainable is this logic:

```
$users = [$user1, $user2];

if (in_array($userrow['name'], $users)) {
    // Username exists
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are doing the first check right, but checking `$user2` gives you `true` because `if("Admin")` is `true`.

Change

```
if ($userrow['name'] == $user1 || $user2 )
```

To

```
if ($userrow['name'] == $user1 || $userrow['name'] == $user2 )
```